# Function not executing properly when being called by button click

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, transient

I have an ajax request that looks like this:

```
  $('#clear_cache').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var ajaxurl = "clearcache.php";
      $.post(ajaxurl, function () {
          $('<p>The cache was cleared successfully.</p>').insertAfter('#clear_cache');
      });
  });
```

The clearcache.php file looks like this:

```
do_action( 'clear_terms', 'clear_transients' );

function clear_transients() {
global $wpdb;
$sql = "delete from {$wpdb->options}
where option_name like '_transient_cc%'";
return $wpdb->query($sql);
}
```

I know the ajax request is linking ok to the php file because when I clear out the php file and click on my button the request is made. I feel like there's something wrong with my PHP file, like the function hasn't been setup correctly or I am making the wrong request type. However when I tested out this php code out in the same file as where my button is located it works ok (but this was using a query string method). Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: How does *clearcache.php* have access to WordPress functions?

Comment: Have you loaded wordpress in clearcache.php?

Comment: You should really consider getting rid of the PHP file, and use [`wp_ajax_(action)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side) actions instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see a couple things wrong here. If you are using ajax with WordPress you should be running it through the admin ajax url.

You aren't using `do_action` properly. The first parameter is the name of the action and the second should be the arguments for the action. I think you are confusing `do_action` with `add_action`.

It's best practice to use `die()` or better yet `wp_die()` when you finish your ajax handler. Alternatively if you are returning some output you can use `wp_send_json()`

Your `ajaxurl` should always point to the admin-ajax.php. If you are doing this on the admin side `ajaxurl` is already setup for you. If you are doing this on the frontend you should have a snippet like the following in your functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );

function my_scripts() {
    // the file where your javascript is located    
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery') );

    // this makes the admin url available to your javascript
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

You can then use `ajax_object.ajaxurl` in your javascript to get the right URL.

Your javascript may now look something like this:

```
$('#clear_cache').click(function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = { action: 'clear_transients' }
      $.post( ajax_object.ajaxurl, data, function () {
          $('<p>The cache was cleared successfully.</p>').insertAfter('#clear_cache');
      });
  });
```

If you are running this in the admin just replace `ajax_object.ajaxurl` with `ajaxurl`. Notice the addition of the `data` variable. This will tell WordPress which action it should be running.

For your actions you should be using the `wp_ajax_(action)` for admin side or the `wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)` for the frontend.

This would change your ajax handler function to something like this:

```
// run on the admin side
add_action( 'wp_ajax_clear_transients', 'clear_transients' );

// or run on the frontend
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_clear_transients', 'clear_transients' );

function clear_transients() {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "DELETE FROM {$wpdb->options} WHERE option_name LIKE '_transient_cc%'";
    $wpdb->query($sql);
    wp_die();
}
```

Your ajax handler can also be placed in the functions.php.

One thing I did not mention is [nonces](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces). You should be using nonces for security. Nonces are used with [check_ajax_referer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer) to make sure ajax requests are originating from the correct source.

Comment: Thanks Jrod, what I did in my question is I simplified a few things to try and get to the root cause of the problem, but I realise I should have provided more details so you could have targeted your answer better. For instance this is for a Wordpress Plugin in the admin area. I was actually using the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' method for the jQuery. With all that said you have pointed out a whole range of errors I need to look at. Your response is so detailed very very much appreciated you have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using Wordpress but the Ajax call goes to the php file directly without bootstrapping the required Wordpress files before.

Have a look here for instructions on using Ajax with Wordpress:
https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Hey Rudi, I just want to thank you heaps for sharing that link. Upon reading everything this gave me some sample code I could test out and get up and running. I was able to repurpose this to make everything work woohoo! So I am very excited and thankful for your help. The main problem I see with what I was doing was I was trying to put that PHP code into a seperate file and not reference it properly within the rest of my plugin. Adding the php and jQuery action to my main plugin folder solved all my problems.